# How to automatically shrink lines in align block to fit hbox?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, fontsize

I have written the following latex

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathcal{P}}
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    &H_{n + 1}= \\
    &-\sum_{x_{n + 1}} \P(x_{n + 1} | x_n) \sum_{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n}} \P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \log(\P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)\P(x_{n + 1} | x_n)) =\\
    &-\sum_{x_{n + 1}} \P(x_{n + 1} | x_n) \sum_{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n}} \P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) (\log(\P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)) + \log(\P(x_{n + 1} | x_n))) =\\
    &-\sum_{x_{n + 1}} \P(x_{n + 1} | x_n) H_n - \sum_{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n + 1}} \P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n + 1}) \log(\P(x_{n + 1} | x_n))) =
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

This gives me an overfull hbox warning. Is there a way to automatically shrink each line so that it fits inside the hbox?

Note: I am willing to accept a solution that tells me how to shrink everything in the align contents, but I would greatly prefer an answer that automatically shrinks each line dynamically, and I would love an answer that explains how to do both.

Comment: Which \hbox exactly?

Comment: @Bernard The full error message is "Overfull \hbox (381.39438pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--69". Line 69 is the line containing \end{align*}

Comment: The `&` at the beginning of the first line is automatically forcing everything to the right, though not by very much.  The `multline*` environment of `amsmath` would be more appropriate, although it still won't reduce the width of the second line.  It's not clear what `\P` is defined to be, and it's not possible to know what the output is without knowing that.  Please make your example a complete compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`; that way potential helpers will have something to experiment with.

Comment: This code produces only an ‘Overfull \hbox(4.46786pt)’, which is easy to solve with `mathtools`. For more than 381pt, there must be something else.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry I pasted incomplete latex originally, I edited the question

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the advice, I have edited the question to be more complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to load the `geometry` package, to have more sensible margins and use the `\smashoperator` command from `mathtools` (needless to load amsmath in this case). Without geometry, you'll have to break the second row, for instance with `multlined`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{mathtools}

\renewcommand{\P}{\mathcal{P}}
\date{May 2019}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    &H_{n + 1}= \\
    &-\sum_{x_{n + 1}} \P(x_{n + 1}\mid x_n) \smashoperator{\sum_{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n}}} \P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \log(\P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)\P(x_{n + 1} \mid x_n)) =\\
    &-\begin{multlined}\smash[b]{\sum_{x_{n + 1}}} \P(x_{n + 1}\mid x_n) \smash[b]{\smashoperator{\sum_{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n}}}} \P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)\bigl (\log(\P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)) \\+ \log(\P(x_{n + 1}\mid x_n))\bigr) =
    \end{multlined}\\
    &-\sum_{x_{n + 1}} \P(x_{n + 1}\mid x_n) H_n -\smashoperator{ \sum_{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n + 1}}} \P(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n + 1}) \log(\P(x_{n + 1}\mid x_n))) =
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Unrelated: I replaced the occurrences of `|` in probabilities with `\mid` to have a better horizontal spacing.

[image]